# Microsoft Teams: Need to Provide 'Edit in Teams' for Sharepoint Documents in Custom Tab

Tags: microsoft-teams

Microsoft Teams: Need option to Provide 'Edit in Teams' for Sharepoint Documents in Custom Tab

I need to provide option of 'Edit in Teams' in custom tab containing document library.

I have tried using "microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink('https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/docx/viewer/teams/https:~2F~2Ftenant.sharepoint.com~2Fsites~2FTestTeam~2FShared%20Documents~2FCustom~2FContractExecutableTemplate.docx?threadId=19:7ba74a73a2d04bb19bc417e52c1f5101@thread.skype&baseUrl=https:~2F~2Ftenant.sharepoint.com~2Fsites~2FTestTeam&fileId=603F7416-260C-44FA-AE8E-1E4B7D4C2AC0&ctx=files&viewerAction=edit')"

but it gives error and also directly opening url like

"https://teams.microsoft.com/l/_#/docx/viewer/teams/https:~2F~2Ftenant.sharepoint.com~2Fsites~2FTestTeam~2FShared%20Documents~2FCustom~2FContractExecutableTemplate.docx?threadId=19:7ba74a73a2d04bb19bc417e52c1f5101@thread.skype&baseUrl=https:~2F~2Ftenant.sharepoint.com~2Fsites~2FTestTeam&fileId=603F7416-260C-44FA-AE8E-1E4B7D4C2AC0&ctx=files&viewerAction=edit" 
but it gives launcher page instead of opening the app

Since there is no proper documentation of executeDeepLink any help wpuld be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on from where do you want to give an option to edit in teams? Could you please share a screenshot for better understanding?

Comment: i want to add 'Edit in Team' option in my custom tab (website tab) which contains document library url against each document file. Just like it shows for Files tab

Comment: Could you please try [deeplinking to the tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links?view=msteams-client-js-latest#deep-linking-to-your-tab) containing the sharepoint file and see if you could edit it from there?